# Ways to delay processing of code in Java GUI

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, process, delay, sleep

I'm making a program that delays a set.visible(false) code then after a specified time interval, will set.visible to true.

So far I found two ways to make it work:
1. Use a thread.sleep
2. Use a swing timer

Are there any other ways to delay processes in java?, my code is in GUI tho so I appreciate if your answer can apply to a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor** from the **java.util.concurrent** package.

```
public ScheduledFuture<?> schedule(Runnable command, long delay, TimeUnit unit)
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) is the documentation.

Comment: Thanks alot, i'll be sure to try this out